# Broken link - "/a" in JQuery 1.9 Js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, broken-links

When we had done security audit of our project, we got broken Link "/a" vulnerability.

After searching for link throughout project we found link in JQuery-1.9.js java-script file that we are using in our project.

small part of code  in that JQuery-1.9.js -

```
// Make sure that URLs aren't manipulated
// (IE normalizes it by default)
hrefNormalized: a.getAttribute("href") === "/a",
```

As per my understanding this code part helps for making it(JQuery) compatible with IE 6/7/8.
hrefNormalized is used to check that anchor tag is giving href value as full URL or exact href , which is issue in IE version.
The better explanation of this part is given in
https://www.inkling.com/read/jquery-cookbook-cody-lindley-1st/chapter-4/recipe-4-1

I want to remove this vulnerability but i don't want to remove or change code in JQuery js file.

So, My question is **why did not JQuery designers used "/#" instead of "/a"** .What is the problem of using "/#" in that code.

Earlier same question is asked  by someone to JQuery Team,but they told that it not the problem from Jquery.
For reference of that ticket
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10149

Help me to solve Or Is there another solution?

Thank you

Comment: What is a "broken Link "/a" vulnerability"? It would be easier (and less presumptuous) to change your code to remove the error instead of change jQuery imo.

Comment: A broken link refers to any link that should take you to a document, image or webpage, that actually results in an error.This page was linked from the website but it is inaccessible.

Comment: The vulnarability is originnated from Jquery.It is not part of my code.That's why Is it better to change JQuery

Comment: Perhaps add a page called "a" to your server so that the link is no longer broken.

Comment: Can you provide an article that states what is this vulnerability? In what situation it would cause a problem? Never had any issues with jQuery.

Comment: @Andy Yes I know that solution but I don't want to do that.I want remove root cause of problem

Comment: More info on Broken link http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/broken-links/ And http://www.acunetix.com/blog/docs/finding-broken-links/

Comment: Huh? You said "I want to remove this vulnerability but i don't want to remove or change code in JQuery js file." The solution to add a page called "a" does _exactly_ that.

Comment: jQuery does not break or create links by itself, you are barking the wrong tree, see answer from Wolfgang.

Comment: @Andy Yes i wrote.But i want solution to remove broken link "/a"

Comment: @Esa If you check the code of JQuery,they are actually creating anchor tag with href="a" to verify browser

Comment: @OomphFortuity line number? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: @OomphFortuity as you can see, jQuery only tests the browser capabilities here. The a-tag created is NOT appended to the document at any point. So there is not going to be "broken" link in your document. also the whole jQuery.support that is tested here is deprecated and removed from jQuery 2.x.

Comment: Interesting FACT is that "/a" is Only Present in JQuery 1.X version.It is not present in Next versions that is JQuery 2.X version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a vulnerability but a false positive. The security scanner interprets the "/a" string as a link, which it is not.

Even if jQuery creates the link in the DOM, it's not clickable or visible to the user. Your website does not actually have a real link to /a anywhere.

I would ignore the problem without changing anything.

Comment: Interesting FACT is that "/a" is only present in JQuery 1.X versions.It is not present in JQuery 2.X versions.

Comment: Newer versions do not care about IE 8 compatibility anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you want this `hrefNormalized: a.getAttribute("href") === "/a",` to be transformed into this `hrefNormalized: a.getAttribute("href") === "/#",` but you don't want to touch the jQuery file.
Put that second one in a script in a an order so that the browser reads your script after reading the jQuery file, so it mashes.

Anyway, I never had issues with jQuery before, check your code first.

If you don't want to have your views with scripts, put it in a js file and link this file to your view after the jQuery file.

Hope it helped you, or at least gave you some ideas to solve your problem. Good luck, let us know how it goes! ;)

**EDIT:**

```
<script src="~/JQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Fix.js"></script>
```

If you do something like this, the browser reads first the jQuery, then it reads the Fix.js. Inside the Fix.js, you put the function or paramater you want to change from the jQuery.

So the Browser will get the latest one it reads if they are equal.

For example:

```
function whatever (){   //This in jQuery file
  //things #1
}

function whatever (){   //This in Fix file
  //Different things #2
}
```

This way the browser chooses the Fix.js one, because was the last he read.

Comment: This is not an answer, you just throw some vague toughts around and not event implementation as how your own "idea" could be done.

Comment: @Esa well, I would try that, to see if it actually mashes the jQuery file line, and it fixes the issue. Wasn't with bad intentions.

Comment: Ofcourse, but you should have atleast added the implementation for the idea. I'm sure everyone appreciates that you tried to help :)

Comment: @Esa you are right, I edited, tried to expand myself and explain what I think he could try to fix this. Hope it works. Thank you for the tip. Have a nice day! ;)